# Specific Version of Lambda Edge function not creating Cloudwatch logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I have a lambda edge function that is associated to the Viewer Request event in AWS Cloudfront and it is configured to a specific version of the lambda function (Version:10) . However, even though this lambda is being invoked (in production) and everything is working fine, it does not write to Cloudwatch logs.  If I manually run the "LATEST" or default version of the code , it does produce cloudwatch logs.  But since the Cloudfront configuration requires it to be a specific version number (it does not accept LATEST or alias etc) , I am forced to provide a specific version and it does not produce logs.
This is the error it generates if a function ARN other than a specific version is provided :

> The function ARN must reference a specific function version. (The ARN must end with the version number.) ARN: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxxxx:function:my-edge-function

The lambda function has a role that does include policy to write to cloudwatch :

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:PutLogEvents"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        ]
    }
]
```

This role/policy has not changed.
I have had other lambda functions that I have switched between LATEST and specific version invocations and both will produce logs and indicate the version in the log group name.

Is there anything specific to Cloudfront/Edge that prevents this from happening ?

Tried switching to the default/LATEST version but it is not allowed by Cloudfront.
Tried MANUALLY executing the specific version of the lambda that is invoked from cloudfront..It runs fine and produces a log.
ONLY when it is invoked from Cloudfront does it not produce a Cloudwatch log

Comment: Did you check in which region your lambda is executed when you hit your CloudFront distribution?
It might differ from the region you selected for your deployment and tests.
Check [lambda-edge-testing-debugging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-testing-debugging.html).